# Scroll issue in InfoWindow

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I am facing scroll bar issue in InfowWindow.
I am able to display the content in InfoWindow, but some of the infowindow shows horizontal and verticls scroll bars.
How to avoid this.
On debug in browser, I found that it is Google's div which wraps content having this css code: "overflow:auto". How to remove this css? If if make "overflow:none", then everything looks good, but I am unable to do it in CSS or in Jquery after calling the infoWindow.Open

```
<div style="overflow: auto;">
    <div class='infowindowContent'>
   ......My content goes here...
   </div>
</div>
```

The top div is actually from google map.
All i have to do is just remove that overflow.
Please let me know if anyone has any solution.

I tried this code, but there is no use...

```
infowindow.open(this.getMap(), loc.getGMarker());
$(".infowindowContent").parent().css("overflow", "none");
```

since, i don't want anyother customization for infowindow, I don't want to use InfoBox plug-in, using this it may be possible.

Thanks,
Sharath

Comment: Your jquery idea is great, but without a jsfiddle to mess around giving an answer will be difficult.